# Build error (make gonk)  while compiling B2G

Tags: android, linux, gnu-toolchain

I am working on Boot2Gecko for Nexus S. I started compiling the code yesterday based on the instructions at [Boot2Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla/Boot_to_Gecko/Building_Boot_to_Gecko). Everything is fine but it doesn't compile at one stage and I get following error:

http://pastebin.com/tPqqwdaF. I think its the same error over here https://github.com/andreasgal/B2G/issues/291

Can someone please let me know how I can resolve the build error. Any help will be appreciated!